# Set a hard-coded page-template (post-type-archive) as home/front-page of my wordpress blog?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, options, homepage

under Settings->Reading I can set which page should appear immediately when visiting my site as "home-page".

In my case I want the archive of my custom-post-type named "events" as home/front-page of my site.

So I have a hardcoded item in my navigation that says "Events" that links to /events and uses my custom-post-template to loop through my custom-post-type.

How could I (and what is the best way) set this archive as the automatic home/front-page of my site? I want to avoid unnessecary routing on my page. So when calling "www.mypage.com" I want the archive to appear immedeately.

Any ideas on that? Preferrably even as setting in my "Settings->Reading" section in the backend.

Thank you in advance.
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

Create template and include events archive file

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Index Events
*/
get_template_part( 'category-events' );   // Archive for Events (category-events.php)
?>
```

Then create page using this template and finally select this page in Settings -> Reading